# Efficiently move query results to S3 csv

Tags: ruby, postgresql, amazon-s3

I have a Postgres database somewhere (not necessarily on EC2) and want to move the results of a SQL query to S3 CSV. Something like

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table WHERE col3 > 30;
```

There could potentially be a TON of data coming back.

Is there a more efficient way to do this other than running the query and getting the results into an array, then uploading the array joined with ',' as a string to S3 with Ruby's aws-sdk?

Answer (score 0):

The [COPY command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html) in PostgreSQL does pretty much exactly what you want. It can dump a table or the results of a query as CSV with or without headers, quoting, etc. in a very efficient manner.

I assume since you included the `ruby` tag that you want to do this from Ruby, so here is an example that uses [the support for `COPY` in the `pg` gem](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html#method-i-copy_data) to get you started:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pg'

# Stream data from a query as CSV

$stderr.puts "Opening database connection ..."
conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'thedatabase' )

query = %{
    SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table WHERE col3 > 30
}

$stderr.puts "Running COPY command ..."
buf = ''
conn.copy_data( "COPY (#{query}) TO STDOUT WITH csv" ) do
    $stdout.puts( buf ) while buf = conn.get_copy_data
end

conn.finish
```

You could replace the `$stdout.puts( buf )` bit to instead do the upload to S3 on the fly, or just run it this way, redirect to a file (e.g., `ruby thescript.rb > mydata.csv`), and upload as a separate step.